# After getting a partial answer

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30287368/4519059) and got [a partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30287644/4519059) to it. AFAIK, my question at Stack Overflow is known as answered after that partial answer has 7 votes.

What should I do when a partial answer got votes and my question still is not answered?

Is it good to ask a duplicate question?

Answer (score 4):

Don't ask a duplicate.

Don't accept the partial answer (still upvote it if you wish to), perhaps post a polite comment asking for the rest of the information.

Another option is to place a bounty on your question seeking an authorative or complete answer.

Comment: I added a comment and after upvotings I removed that comment.

Comment: ... and always keep in mind that **partial answers are NOT non-answers and shouldn't be flagged as such**.